# I'm trying to move a Rectangle in a Canvas ( in a WPF app) using the Mouse event but it don't work

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-controls, mouseevent

I develop a wpf application and I have to move a rectangle in a canvas (and the end goal is to make sure my rectangle can not get out of the canvas). So I searched and tried many solutions on the Web, but I was not working yet. Then I tried to rewrite a solution, but it did not work.

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasImplant" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="27,27,26,0" Height="415">
        <Rectangle x:Name="MovableShape" Opacity="0.85" Width="93" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="930,140" Stroke="Black" StrockThickness="1" MouseDown="MovShp_MouseDown" MouseUp="MovShp_MouseUp" MouseMove="MovShp_MouseMove"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

```
private bool drag = true;
private Point StartPt;
private double newX, newY;

private void MovShp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    drag = true;
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    startPt = e.Getposition(CanvasImplant);
    Mouse.Capture((UIElement)sender);
}

private void MovShp_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    drag = false;
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    Mouse.Capture(null);
}

private void MovShp_MouseMove(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (drag)
    {
        double deltaX = e.GetPosition(CanvasImplant).X - startPt.X;
        double deltaY = e.GetPosition(CanvasImplant).Y - startPt.Y;

        newX = deltaX + Canvas.GetLeft(MovableShape);
        newY = deltaY + Canvas.GetTop(MovableShape);

        if (newX < 0)
            newX = 0;
        else if (newX + MovableShape.ActualWidth > CanvasImplant.ActualWidth)
            newX = CanvasImplant.ActualWidth - MovableShape.ActualWidth;

        if (newY < 0)
            newY = 0;
        else if (newY + MovableShape.ActualHeight > CanvasImplant.ActualHeight )
            newY = CanvasImplant.ActualHeight - MovableShape.ActualHeight ;

        MovableShape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newX);
        MovableShape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newY);
    }

}
```

When I click on MovableShape, the mouse becomes a hand and when I release the left mouse button, it becomes an arrow, but when I drag the rectangle, it does not follow the mouse and when I release the click, it do not move.

Comment: Attach the mouse event handlers to the Canvas, not the Rectangle. Set `Background=Transparent"` on the Canvas to get mouse input.

Comment: You also need to set initial values for Canvas.Left and Top. Their default value are `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things.

1. you need to set the Fill on the shape otherwise your click
   events only fire on the very thin border
2. the mouse move and mouse up event needs to be the Canvas events, not
   the shape
3. you need to set startPt to the new position each time in the
   move event handler
4. you need to remove the margin and horizontal/vertical position for the shape
5. you need to capture the mouse using the Canvas not the shape

This works for me:

```
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid"  >
    <Canvas x:Name="CanvasImplant" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseMove="MovShp_MouseMove"  MouseUp="MovShp_MouseUp" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="20" x:Name="MovableShape" Fill="Transparent"  Opacity="0.85" Width="93" Height="62" Stroke="Black" 
                   StrokeThickness="1" MouseDown="MovShp_MouseDown" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

And the handlers:

```
private void MovShp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    drag = true;
    Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    startPt = e.GetPosition(CanvasImplant);
    Mouse.Capture(CanvasImplant);
}

private void MovShp_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    drag = false;
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    Mouse.Capture(null);
}

private void MovShp_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (drag)
    {
        var mp = e.GetPosition(CanvasImplant);
        double deltaX = mp .X - startPt.X;
        double deltaY = mp .Y - startPt.Y;

        var newX = deltaX + Canvas.GetLeft(MovableShape);
        var newY = deltaY + Canvas.GetTop(MovableShape);

        if (newX < 0)
            newX = 0;
        else if (newX + MovableShape.ActualWidth > CanvasImplant.ActualWidth)
            newX = CanvasImplant.ActualWidth - MovableShape.ActualWidth;

        if (newY < 0)
            newY = 0;
        else if (newY + MovableShape.ActualHeight > CanvasImplant.ActualHeight)
            newY = CanvasImplant.ActualHeight - MovableShape.ActualHeight;

        Canvas.SetLeft(MovableShape, newX);
        Canvas.SetTop(MovableShape, newY);

        startPt = mp ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Rectangle don't have GetLeft(), GetTop(), SetLeft() or SetTop() method. I tried to just Fill the rectangle, set the canvas background to transparent and replace the margin propertie with Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top and now my rectangle move but it is stuck around the canvas's left boundarie and while I keep the mouse button pressed, my rectangle blink from each side of the boundarie.

Comment: sorry my mistake, see edit.  use canvas.getleft etc

Comment: Have you used any special header for this app?

Comment: @GuillaumeMts if the above now works please upvote and mark as answer. thanks

Comment: Well actually it's work but it just don't respect the bottom and right boundaries of the canvas and I don't really know why, so thanks